# emacs - show help and message buffer in current window or in separate frame?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have been working with emacs in a semi-full-screen configuration where my frame is 160 chars wide and as tall as the screen. In this layout I have my windows split in a certain way that I like. I wonder if there is a way to make help files and messages (e.g., the output when I run an asynchronous shell) pop up either in the same window where my (point) is located when I invoke help or the shell command, or in a separate frame so as not to disturb my window layout and the buffers contained in them? I have tried elscreen and winner-mode; the latter does restore my window layout but requires me to cycle through windows to close the help or message buffer (rather than C-x k on the spot, it if was in the same buffer)...

Thanks, Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to roll your own (sounds like you have some pretty specific ideas on what you want).  All the information you need to get started can be found on the ["Choosing Windows"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html) section of the elisp manual.  It sounds like `same-window-buffer-names` and/or `same-window-regexps` and `same-window-p` will give you what you want, though these others might fit the bill: `special-display-buffer-names`, `speical-display-regexps`, `special-display-function`, `display-buffer-function`.

Comment: Yes! same-window-buffer-names and same-window-regexps are the functions I wanted. Thanks!!

Comment: and '(pop-up-windows nil) also - all there on that delightful page.

Answer (score 0):

See One-On-One Emacs for code that implements a special-display `*Help*` buffer -- IOW, `*Help*` pops up in its own frame.

The code is here:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/oneonone.el

See this part:

```
  ;; *Help* frame
  (if 1on1-*Help*-frame-flag
      (add-to-list
       'special-display-buffer-names
       (list "*Help*" '1on1-display-*Help*-frame
             (list (cons 'background-color 1on1-help-frame-background)
                   (cons 'mouse-color 1on1-help-frame-mouse+cursor-color)
                   (cons 'cursor-color 1on1-help-frame-mouse+cursor-color)
                   '(height . 40))))
    (setq special-display-buffer-names
          (remove-if (lambda (elt) (equal "*Help*" (car elt)))
                     special-display-buffer-names)))
```